# In the Dragonlance setting, can a dragon recognize that a player character is a wizard?

Tags: dnd-5e, wizard, dragonlance

In the Dragonlance setting, can a dragon recognize that a player character is a wizard, if they are a 2nd-level wizard trying to hide that fact?

Comment: Is there a reason why you think a dragon would (or wouldn't) be able to tell a player's class, mechanically speaking? Is there anything unique to the Dragonlance setting that you think might affect this?

Comment: @V2Blast isn't that the question they're asking?

Comment: @Wibbs: Sort of. I'm just trying to understand the context of the question, and what information the asker is working off of. (In other words: why would a dragon know a character's class, in Dragonlance or any other setting?)

Comment: @V2Blast Dragons are smart.

Comment: How are you 'hiding that fact'?

Comment: If they have anything to hide then yes. Dragons can detect hidden things "at a glance".

Comment: @Mast That doesn't really answer V2Blast's question in any way. "Smart" is a relative term measuring IQ, and V2Blast's question is about a binary ability to discern a class or the presence of magical ability.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

No.

Wizards are not different to anyone else, as they don't have an inner power source, but manage the magic via Solinari, Lunitari or Nuitari, just like a cleric would.
As long as said wizard isn't keeping any spells up, like Mage Armor, or doesn't wear anything magic that can identify him as a wizard, like a magic arcane focus or a spell-protected tome that the dragon can "Detect Magic" on, your wizard is safe.

The dragon can, though, deduce it. Remember that they are supposed to be keenly intelligent and have better senses than humans. A Dragon could smell the special ink wizards use to write on their tomes, or even see traces of it in their fingers; maybe smell traces of some common material components; he could maybe deduce it from clues in a conversation; it could cast a mind reading spell or ability; or it could have spies or previous information on the wizard.

That being said, no, Dragons do not have any specific ability that lets them detect if a mortal is a wizard or if said wizard has passed the Test or not. They can still deduce or investigate it, like any other intelligent creature would.

Comment: 2nd level sounds a bit early to have already done the Test. In 3e the DLCS put it after 5th level.

Comment: It might be, I don't remember really. I half remembered it was really early in a Wizard's career and since the asker said 2nd level... But it does not affect the answer, does it?

Comment: no, the answer is good. You might add that the presence of an unarmed and unarmored individual in an armed party might also be a giveaway of their role.

Comment: Well, the question says that the wizard is trying to hide the fact that he is, so I guess an intelligent wizard would not make that mistake. But anyway I also said the dragon can deduce it, and that would be deducting, even if it's on the nose :P